What is this movie with all objects being boxes that get scanned and become something else
I remember from a long time ago, probably 10-15 years ago a movie where at one point there were two main characters escaping some bad guys and they were supposedly in this "utopian living area".  They found themselves in some sort of factory that had boxes with barcodes on them getting scanned and then becoming something new, such as a couch or tv.  They then had to escape from the bad guys and did so by finding an "invisible" sewer entrance because of the wind that was escaping it.
I honestly don't recall much else, so any help on finding this movie would be great!

Maybe "Virtual Nightmare" (2000)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVZgPPYACy0

I'll check that out once I finish work to see if it's right :)  Thanks!

@pori - post your answer! :o)

"Virtual Nightmare "(2000)

A man drives around his small hometown in a brand new convertible. The
  style of everything is 1950's but people have cell-phones, HDTV and
  computers-and an announcer on the radio says something about Kurt
  Cobain's children's christmas album coming out soon. Indeed a very
  different world. This man starts seeing things, though, like numbers
  and bar codes on everyday items-even seeing his parents as crippled,
  burned-out looking people. In fact, the more he sees these things the
  more he suspects that his own reality isn't real. It's finally
  revealed to him by a group of people that it's really a hundred years
  later than he thinks it is and that people live in this type of
  virtual reality because reality is simply too horrible after the wars
  and devastation. The people in the domed cities control the virtual
  reality. He believes this for a while-until he figures out that even
  this new reality is still virtual reality and that the real world is
  something else entirely.




